# How to attach CloudWatchLogsFullAccess to the IAM role of EKS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I use the module, terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws provision EKS. By default, the module provisions three policies to the EKS EC2 IAM role, AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy, AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly and AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy. I would like to attach an additional policy, CloudWatchLogsFullAccess to the IAM role. I read the doc. I did not find a way to attach it. I had to logon to the AWS console, manually attach CloudWatchLogsFullAccess to the IAM role. Is there a way to use terraform code to attach it when I use this EKS module provisioning EKS?

I added the code below.

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "cloudWatch" {
  role       = module.eks.cluster_iam_role_arn
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess"
}
```

But, it complains "The specified value for roleName is invalid".
Error: Error attaching policy arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess to IAM Role arn:aws:iam::678515134618:role/my-eks20210303061731134400000005: ValidationError: The specified value for roleName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_-
status code: 400, request id: aee57a35-ae72-499e-8653-e61e795818e4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create your eks cluster, you can get [cluster_iam_role_arn](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/outputs.tf#L44)_from its outputs. Having the ARN you can attach extra policies to it using [aws_iam_role_policy_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy_attachment):

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  role       = module.myeks.cluster_iam_role_arn
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess"
}
```

Comment: I added the resource per your comments. See the code I pasted above. But, I got errors.
Error: Error attaching policy arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess to IAM Role arn:aws:iam::678515134618:role/my-eks20210303061731134400000005: ValidationError: The specified value for roleName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_- status code: 400, request id: aee57a35-ae72-499e-8653-e61e795818e4. What I did wrong?

Comment: @MelissaJenner It looks like role name contains some invalid characters.